# AWS DynamoDB table structure?

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

What is the best way to structure table on DynamoDB for below purposes?

If I make an app for movie review, I need a movie page with reviews on that movie and user account page with all the reviews that users wrote on the app.

**movie table**

```
-------------------------
| movie_id | movie_name |
-------------------------
```

**review table**

```
---------------------------------------------------
| review_id | movie_id | user_id | review_content |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Does it make sense for DynamoDB? so I can query 
`movie_id` and `movie_name` on the movie page and list `review_content` by `movie_id`
then
query `review_content` by `user_id` on user account page.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like RDBMS, you don't need to normalize the data i.e. don't create two different tables. The important point on NoSQL database is that keep most of the required data for the use case in one table if possible.

Assuming the above data wouldn't exceed **400 KB maximum limit** for an item (i.e. maximum limit of an item in DynamoDB), you can keep all the data in one table.

**Proposed Data Model:-**

Create one table called **`Movie`** with all the required information. The good thing about your use case is that you know the partition key i.e. `movie_id`. You can use the **Query API** available in DynamoDB to get the data by `movie_id` which will give you all the `user_ids` who have written the review comments for the `movie_id`.

In this approach, you don't to get the review data separately from another table which will **save you cost and provide better performance**.

**Movie Table:**

movie_id    ==> Partition Key

user_id     ==> Sort key

movie_name

review_id

review_content

**Note:-**

I don't understand the purpose of `review_id` unless you have a separate use case to get the details by `review_id`.

**EDIT - Json Format:-**

The `user_id` is a SORT key. It should come outside `reviews`.

```
{
  "movie_id" : 1,
  "user_id" : "1"   
  "movie_name" "Name of movie",
  "review_comments" : ["A great movie", "I love it"]                
}
```

**Partition and sort key:-**

> For a composite primary key (partition key and sort key), you must
>   provide exactly two elements, in this order: The first element must
>   have a KeyType of HASH, and the second element must have a KeyType of
>   RANGE.
>
> Partition Key and Sort Key—A composite primary key composed of two
>   attributes. The first attribute is the partition key, and the second
>   attribute is the sort key. DynamoDB uses the partition key value as
>   input to an internal hash function; the output from the hash function
>   determines the partition where the item will be stored. All items with
>   the same partition key are stored together, in sorted order by sort
>   key value. It is possible for two items to have the same partition key
>   value, but those two items must have different sort key values.

In the above model, we have hash and sort key which uniquely identifies the item (i.e. record in RDBMS). The hash key is `movie_id` and sort key is `user_id`. One movie_id can have multiple user_id which forms multiple items (i.e. RDBMS terms it is called records) in the DynamoDB table.

**Example:-**

```
movie id 1, user id 1, movie name 1, review comments 1
movie id 1, user id 2, movie name 1, review comments 2
movie id 2, user id 3, movie name 2, review comments 1
```

As we discussed previously, `review_comments` is a Dynamodb List or Set data type which can have multiple values.

Comment: Thank you or the response @notionquest I have not used DynamoDB yet and have a question on your table structure. How is the data gets stored if there's more than one reviews on a movie? It will have same data except for `review_content`? it's it's coming from same user.

Comment: If the same user writes review comments for the same movie, you can make review_comment attribute as Set or List data type in order to store multiple comments.

Comment: Updated the structure in the answer. The user_id should be outside review_comments.

Comment: Thank you. That explains how one user makes multiple reviews but how do I use that for multiple users make review on `movie_id: 1` ?

Comment: I have updated the details about partition and sort key. Hope it clarifies your doubt. If not, please read about partition and sort key of DynamoDB table. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.html#WorkingWithTables.primary.key